# Am I missing indentation or is something else wrong with this?

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "guess_secret"

@app.route('/') 
def landing_page():
    if 'num' not in session:
        session['num'] = random.randrange(0,101)
    if 'message' not in session:
        session['message'] = ''
    if 'color' not in session:
        session['color'] = ''
    return render_template('indexa.html', msg = session['message'], color = session['color'])

@app.route('/execute', methods=['POST'])
def check_guess():
    session(['guess']) = int(request.form['guess'])
if (session['guess']==session['num']):
    session['message'] = str(session['num'])+'was the number!'
    session['color']='green'
elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['num']:
    session['message'] = 'Too low.'
    session['color']='red'
else: 
    session['message'] = 'Too high.'
    session['color']='red'
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/reset', methods=['POST'])
def reset():
    session.pop('number') 
    session.pop('guess')
    session.pop('color')
    return redirect('/')

app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to create a guessing game flask page.
keeps coming back "File "guess.py", line 27     session['color']='red' ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe you've mixed tabs and spaces. Either use only tabs or only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the code seems to be syntactically right, it looks as if this part:

```
@app.route('/execute', methods=['POST'])
def check_guess():
    session(['guess']) = int(request.form['guess'])
if (session['guess']==session['num']):
    session['message'] = str(session['num'])+'was the number!'
    session['color']='green'
elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['num']:
    session['message'] = 'Too low.'
    session['color']='red'
else: 
    session['message'] = 'Too high.'
    session['color']='red'
    return redirect('/')
```

was probably meant to be this:

```
@app.route('/execute', methods=['POST'])
def check_guess():
    session(['guess']) = int(request.form['guess'])
    if (session['guess']==session['num']):
        session['message'] = str(session['num'])+'was the number!'
        session['color']='green'
    elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['num']:
        session['message'] = 'Too low.'
        session['color']='red'
    else: 
        session['message'] = 'Too high.'
        session['color']='red'
    return redirect('/')
```

Also be sure not to mix tabs and spaces. If you use spaces for indent, make sure there are no tabs at all in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not indented correctly try below code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "guess_secret"

@app.route('/') 
def landing_page():
    if 'num' not in session:
        session['num'] = random.randrange(0,101)
    if 'message' not in session:
        session['message'] = ''
    if 'color' not in session:
        session['color'] = ''
    return render_template('indexa.html', msg = session['message'], color = session['color'])

@app.route('/execute', methods=['POST'])
def check_guess():
    session(['guess']) = int(request.form['guess'])
if (session['guess']==session['num']):
    session['message'] = str(session['num'])+'was the number!'
    session['color']='green'
elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['num']:
    session['message'] = 'Too low.'
    session['color']='red'
else: 
    session['message'] = 'Too high.'
    session['color']='red'
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/reset', methods=['POST'])
def reset():
    session.pop('number') 
    session.pop('guess')
    session.pop('color')
    return redirect('/')

app.run(debug=True)
```